# Class not found Excecption while trying to debug

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox

i am using pdfbox to convert a pdf file into text content.But when i try to debug,it gives me class not found exception.this happens only in debug mode.If i directly run the code it gets executed without any problem. i am suppose to do something else other than just adding pdfbox.jar in the buildpath ? [image: this is the exception i am getting]

Comment: It seems you are missing the source jar for the code you are trying to debug.

Comment: how you manage project i.e. Maven etc ?

Comment: yeah its a maven project.@usman

Comment: yeah that must be the case . but i have downloaded the jars n put in buildpath. what else am i suppose to do ? @mhasan

Comment: Just click on the lookup button shown on your screenshot and locate and load the particular jar file which contains the class you want to debug

Comment: Please inspect the exception and find out which class cannot be loaded.